# Chromeに搭載されている要素を検証では何が出来る？

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Chromeブラウザで右クリックすると一番下に「要素を検証」というメニューが表示されます。

すると画面下にhtmlと思われる言語が書かれた領域が出ます。
これは何に使うものですか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

「要素を検証」メニューは、Chromeに標準で含まれているデベロッパーツールに含まれる物で、Web開発者やデザイナーがHTMLやCSS、Javascriptなどの状態をチェックしたり、どのような構造になっているのかを確認するためのツールです。

使い方などは[gihyo.jpの記事](http://gihyo.jp/dev/feature/01/devtools/0001)などで紹介されていますので、興味がおありでしたら参照ください。

Answer (score 2):

今現在の HTML がどうなっているか確認する際に使用します。(JavaScript などで 動的に DOM 操作を行っているようなページで使います。)

Answer (score 2):

htmlの開発を行う時に使用します。
cookieの中身やjavascriptの動作、htmlの構造やcssの値等々の確認 編集が可能です

Answer (score 0):

使い方によっては、広告を消して印刷を行うこともできます
コードを右クリックで削除するだけですが、